# Missing "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*" in registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, 32-bit

The specific subfolder "*" is missing under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes"

If anyone has enountered this, how can this be fixed, if it can be fixed?

I needed this when trying to follow instructions on adding custom entries to the context-menu on files (like [here](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/18140/how-to-get-windows-explorer-right-click-menu-open-edit-with-notepad?_=1690495786320) )

My platform:

Windows 7 Ultimate, 32 bit, Service pack 1

Registry editor: version 6.1

Comment: Please show a screenshot as to how it looks for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a "*" class, you add it.

If it's not there already, it just means that you don't presently have any user-specific * menu items -- which is normal. Most software is installed for everybody who uses the machine, and particularly the kind of software that is generic for any kind of file.

The * class is for 'everything', which is a common setting for Notepad++, if you want to be able to open 'everything' with Npp.